# How to find and set the text to UILabel of UITableViewCell in Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I use `Http get` to get the `json data` and parse it.

It works fine so far and it shows the data on the `UITableView`.
I have a `UITableCell` in `UITableView`. 
And the cell also has three `UILabel-s` in it like in the following picture.

[image]

And I have set the `Identifier` of `TableViewCell` to "Cell" like in the following picture.
[image]

I want to set `"AAA" , "BBB" , "CCC"` to the `UILebel-s` in `UITableViewCell`, but in the following code, I can not find any `UILabel` in `UITableViewCell`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.

        return cell
    }
```

Should I need to connect the `UILabel` to Swift file?

How to find and set the text to `UILabel` of `UITableViewCell`?

Did I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reason why you can not access the labels in the code is that you have no connection of labels with the code, by adding labels only on the default `UITableViewCell` just won't work.

I suppose you are using custom UITableViewCell? if not then use a custom cell and add three labels in the code and connect them on UI as outlets and in your code you can access them by using cell.label1 and so on

```
  class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet var label1:UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var label2:UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var label3:UILabel!

    }
```

In your main tableview class you could access them like as follows

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell

        cell.label1.text = "AAAA"
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , I can find the UILabel !.

But , can I  add three `labels` in the code same as `UIViewController` and do not create a new `swift class` for `UITableViewCell` ?

Comment: Yes you can but then you won't be using them on the `UITableViewCell` you could just connect them outlet from your viewcontroller and access them like `label1.text`. but if you want them to be visible in every row then it won't serve your purpose, then better to use custom as i showed in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this by giving every label a unique tag and then access that label in the `ViewController` with the tag property then your `cellforRowatIndexpath` will change to following code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? CustomTableViewCell {

        if let label1 = cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel { // 1 is tag of first label
            label1.text = "AAAA"
        }
        if let label2 = cell.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel { // 2 is tag of second label
            label2.text = "BBBB"
        }
        if let label3 = cell.viewWithTag(3) as? UILabel { // 3 is tag of third label
            label3.text = "CCCC"
        }
        return cell

    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Hope it will help you.